# Errors in setting permissions for Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, debian

I am trying to setup Symfony2 on my Vagrant virtual machine.

When navigating to `BASE_RULE/web/app_dev.php`, this is the permission error I am receiving:

`RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/app/cache/dev/classes.php".`

Reading various StackOverflow threads and trying many different proposed solutions, people recommended me to use this Symfony2 Permissions [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions).

I have tried number `2`, but since my system does not support `chmod +a`, I moved onto number `3`:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

When I execute the `setfacl` commands, here are the following errors:

```
vagrant@order-online:/var/www/app$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX cache logs
setfacl: cache: Operation not supported
setfacl: cache/.DS_Store: Operation not supported
setfacl: cache/dev: Operation not supported
setfacl: cache/dev/annotations: Operation not supported
setfacl: cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php: Operation not supported
setfacl: cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php.meta: Operation not supported
setfacl: cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml: Operation not supported
setfacl: cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerCompiler.log: Operation not supported
```

So this one didn't work (or I am missing something..), so I moved onto number `4`, which is setting `umask(0000);` under `app/console, web/app.php and web/app_dev.php`.

After applying that change in those three file locations, I cleared my cache, restarted Vagrant and Apache, but still received the same errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Check that the user for the CLI and the web server are in THE SAME  group

Comment: Hi @Matteo. I actually did not quite understand what that solution was asking me to do. I am aware that since I am using Apache, I have an `./apache2.conf`, but how do I `set its user to be the same as your CLI user (e.g. for Apache, update the User and Group values).`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be your group permissions. Check what user your webserver is using. If you're using nginx, you can usually find this in `/etc/nginx/pool.d/www.conf`. It's usually something like `www-data`. So you'd do: `$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/your-symfony-project`

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to change the cache and log permissions to be editable by the www-data and other groups.
So just do this
chmod -R 777 app/cache/* app/logs/*

Comment: chmod 777 is not a right answer. Change permissions to right user/group instead.https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/why-chmod-777-is-not-secure